# Using NSTimer to shutdown app

Tags: iphone, cocoa, nstimer

Bit of a noob here.

I am developing an app that plays some looped sounds.  I would like to give the user the ability to shut down the app after a certain amount of time using a timer. The idea is the user presses a button and the app will shut down once the timer runs out.

At the moment if the button is pressed, the app crashes.

Here's what I got so far:

```
- (IBAction)timer:(id)sender{

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval: 10.0 target:self selector:@selector(targetMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];

}


-(void) targetMethod: (NSTimer*) theTimer {
    NSLog(@"timer?");
    exit(0);

}
```

Comment: Your code looks reasonable, assuming that timer is a retain property I guess? Next thing to do would be to put NSLog messages before and after the [timer scheduledTimer...] call, and another NSLog in the targetMethod:

Comment: One other thing to look for is to make sure that when you declare the IBAction in the header that you are declaring it identically to the way you declare it in the .m -(IBAction) timer:(id)sender and that it is wired up correctly in the xib. If you see something on crash like "unrecognized selector" and/or you don't see those log messages firing then you haven't wired it up quite right

Comment: Apple won't approve any app that deliberately shuts itself down. If you're going to do this, don't expect the App Store to be an avenue for publication.

Comment: @Tommy this seems like a valid user scenario, though. A better option might be to somehow send it to the background instead, or putting the device to sleep as if the sleep button had been pressed, if that's possible.

Comment: Agreed about the app being rejected for shutting itself down. Rather than shutting the app down, you can simply stop playing the sounds. Same effect for the user.

Comment: I agree with Tommy that Apple won't approve such type of application.Well why would you do that to close the app.The user would have a bad experience as the app close,assume just like crashing.Just put the user on the main screen after that time.

Comment: I wasn't aware apple would refuse to publish an app with this feature, thanks. I will consider something else, possibly sending to the home screen. I am pretty sure everything is wired up right and the timer is a retain property, specified in the header file i.e, @propery (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *timer;                        @MahataManic The NSLog statement prints to the console but "unrecognized selector" appears. I will check out the wiring up, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly define your timer reference:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval: 10.0 target:self selector:@selector(targetMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
```

Comment: As @jsumners notes, you're missing the `NSTimer *` at the beginning of your timer declaration. You need to specify the type and that it's a pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I probably should add I have the timer declared in the header file as such: NSTimer *timer;  I will check the code to make sure all suggestions made are present in thr code.

Comment: SOLVED!  I had NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval: 10.0 target:self selector:@selector(targetMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES]; instead ofNSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 10.0 target:self selector:@selector(targetMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES]; I left out Time before Interval. Thanks to everyone for the replies.